# Github Actions outcome is not retrieved

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, building-github-actions, github-actions-services

I'm attempting to run the following `.yml` with GitHub Actions, but the outcome from the steps is not retrieved or null.

The documentation for outcome is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions).

```yaml
name: run test for outcome
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  run-test-for-outcome:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: step1
        id: step1
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          echo step 1

      - name: test
        run : echo ${{ steps.step1.outcome }}
```

However, if I run the following:

```yaml
name: run test for outcome
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  run-test-for-outcome:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: step1
        id: step1
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          echo step 1

      - name: test
        run : echo ${{ steps.step1.success }}
```

the value returned is true.

Why is that? Why isn't `outcome` working as intended?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the problem
I was running the workflow locally using https://github.com/nektos/act and that appears to be the problem.
When I did test it under Github, the outcome and every step context is working as intended.

Thank you.